# Logging IP address used by urlfetch on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We'd like to log the public facing IP address used in the urlfetch calls in Python to assist our customers in debugging when some calls fail but others succeed. I've had a look through the documentation but can't see a way to do this. The protoPayload IP address already in the logs looks to be the internal network IP address.

Cheers

Comment: I'd be surprised if this were possible - as I understand it, the urlfetch service could theoretically run on any machine in any Google data centre, it's independent of the machine(s) that are running your instances.  Maybe add an identifiable query parameter to the url?